# Attempting to paint window black using JFrame and JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paint

I've made a JFrame, and added a JPanel to it. I am trying to paint the window completely black, and it isn't working! Thank you in advance.

This is my Main class!

```
package com.lootdatdungeon.net;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){

    initWindow();

}

public static void initWindow(){

    Window window = new Window();
    Thread windowThread = new Thread(window);
    windowThread.start();

}

}
```

Okay, and here is my Window class!

```
package com.lootdatdungeon.net;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Window extends JFrame implements Runnable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final int HEIGHT = 240;
private static final int WIDTH = 320;
private static final int SCALE = 2;

private BufferedImage image;
private Graphics2D g;

private boolean running = true;

public Window(){

    System.out.println("Window object made");

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Loot dat dungeon");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    frame.setSize(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(panel);

    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

}

public void Draw(Graphics g){

    System.out.println("Draw method ran");
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);


}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(running){
    Draw(g);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();` **Don't** use `getGraphics`. **Do**, look at the tutorial for [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: It can't really go wrong at this point in time since the Image isn't actually added to anything yet. its just an off-screen buffer that remains off-screen forever more.

Comment: Then of course there is the `Thread` going into an infinite loop to draw. It should be a Swing `Timer` calling `repaint()` instead..

Comment: Thanks for the link peeskillet!

Answer (score 1):

Simply do in this way using overriiden `paintComponent()` method of `JPanel`

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // don't forget to call it
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // set color
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // fill a rect that cover whole panel with specified color
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
};
```

Note: There is no need of Thread and BufferedImage in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should give this a read http://www.gametutorial.net/article/Java-game-framework

That site has a lot of good info if you want to create games. That's there I started.